# How to access persistent data path in Android programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to access installed application persistent folders which is located at */data/data/**

I'm only getting my app folder using this `getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()`.

Is there any way to get all apps persistent folder?

Comment: if device is rooted you will need to invoke a command to gain root access first, then create `File()` to the target app path, ex `/data/data/app.package.name`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't (on non-rooted phones), for obvious security reasons.

You actually cannot even list */data/data/* or */data/app/* without root, even using `adb`...

Comment: Actually i have rooted phone and I want to get that directory list programmatically, is it possible?

Comment: If you request that listing using root privileges, yes. Just like `adb shell su -c 'ls -l /data/data/'` works. Otherwise, no, never.

Comment: Can  you please explain more? I know it is possible with shell adb but i want to do programmatically.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials / libraries for root commands in Android applications: https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools https://github.com/dschuermann/superuser-commands etc.

Comment: Hope you'll get root commands working, it has been a while since I used those libraries. Just so you know: there might be better/newer ones out there ;)